# Exception in BizTalk with Two-Way receive port direct binding

Tags: biztalk, correlation

I have the same problem as described [here](http://www.biztalkgurus.com/biztalk_server/biztalk_2006_r2/f/13/t/10087.aspx):

> I am using two orchestrations. First orchestration calls the second using direct binding through a two-way send port. Second orchestrion has a two-way receive port to send the result back to the first. Every thing is working as it should but I am getting the following exception.
>
> `A response message for two-way receive port "Unknown " is being suspended as the messaging engine could not correlate the response to an existing request message. This usually happens when the host process has been recycled.`

And the suggested solution works as well (*set the BTS.EpmRRCorrelationToken value to a random value, new GUID in my case, in the first orchestration before send to the direct binding port and then in the secod orchestration i copy the value from the inputMessage to the outputMessage, so the value remains the same. With this method BizTalk knows how to correlate the response back to the caller*). But I can't understand why this works and if this a good way to solve the problem. The `BTS.EpmRRCorrelationToken` flow is the following:
[image: UML]

When I don't change the `BTS.EpmRRCorrelationToken` property, it is the same in all messages which flow in the process, but why on Earth doesn't BizTalk change it instead if it can't correctly correlate the messages?

Comment: I checked the solution once again and found that I don't even need to copy `BTS.EpmRRCorrelationToken` in the second Orchestration! The thing I need to do is only to fill `BTS.EpmRRCorrelationToken` in the 1st Orchestration with a newly generated Guid. But why?

Comment: Not sure if you've read this : http://bveldhoen.wordpress.com/2010/09/05/messaging-only-request-response-correlation/. Out of interest, why not call the second orchestration with an output message (OK, albeit coupled), or just use separate send and receive ports (and your own correlation)?

Comment: I've read the article, thanks. I don't want to do extra-work to set up correlations. I just want a published message to be picked up with an orchestration that is designed for the message type\context. For instance, when I publish a message with the "NEW" status, I want that this message would be picked up and processed by NewMessageOrchestration and not by ProcessedMessageOrchestration or any other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing this property is certanly OK in your case.

The problem is direct binding. When you use it, you actually going more "low-level" way and have to deal with how BTS publish-subscribe mechanism works.

Send-Receive port subscribes to receive a message with a specific BTS.EpmRRCorrelationToken. So when you post receive message again in the Message box (for second orch), receive port grabs it too and unsubscribes then. When you finally try to send a response - there is noone waiting for it. So you have to change that property until you sending response back to the port.